# Four-photon polarisation tensor in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, perturbation-theory, ward-identity

Let's consider the four-photon polarisation tensor $\Pi^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}$ in QED. It follows from Ward identity that
$$
k_1^\mu \Pi_{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4) = 0.
$$
After applying the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial k_1^\sigma}$ to both sides of the above equality we obtain
$$
\Pi_{\sigma\nu\lambda\rho}(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4) = -k_1^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial k_1^\sigma}\Pi_{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4).
$$
Thus, $\Pi_{\sigma\nu\lambda\rho}$ vanishes for $k_1=k_2=k_3=k_4=0$.

I cannot reproduce the above result by direct calculaition in one-loop approximation. There are six contributing diagrams in this order, all with one fermionic loop. The three depicted below 
[image]
and another three witch differ only in the arrow direction (they give the same integrals as the diagrams above). I'm interested only in a value of the polarisation tensor for vanishing external momenta of photons. We have 
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho} = T^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho} + T^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda} + T^{\mu\lambda\nu\rho},$$
where
$$T^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}=2(-ie)^4 i^4
\int\frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{\text{tr}\left((m+\gamma \cdot p)\gamma ^{\mu }(m+\gamma \cdot p)\gamma ^{\nu
   }(m+\gamma \cdot p)\gamma ^{\lambda }(m+\gamma \cdot p)\gamma ^{\rho }\right)}{(p^2-m^2+i0)^4}.
$$
The integral in the definition of $T^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}$ is logarithmically divergent but the divergent contribution to $\Pi^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}$ vanishes. Finally I get finite answer for $\Pi_{\sigma\nu\lambda\rho}(k_1=k_2=k_3=k_4=0)$ which is unfortunatelly different from $0$?

Does $\Pi_{\sigma\nu\lambda\rho}(k_1=k_2=k_3=k_4=0)$ really vanish?